# how to replace multiple lines in a file after a specific character with null in unix

Tags: unix, sed

For example, if my file contains

```
{z:
abdc
cabdfd
cabdfd
casfdbf
cdff
-}$
```

Once find the string value `{z:` the multiple lines after that upto `-}` must be replaced by null character and it should follow the same procedure globally throughout the file.

This must be done in Unix I tried using `sed` command to search for multiple lines but unable to succeed with it though.

Comment: What did you try? Can you give some approach you wrote so far? Post also a representative input file and desired output. Finally: what is the null character?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify an address range in `sed` so that the action is performed for lines within the range

**To delete the lines within the two pattern**

```
$ cat input
{z:
abdc
cabdfd
cabdfd
casfdbf
cdff
-}$
hello
world

$ sed '/^{z:$/, /$-}\$$/d' input
hello
world
```

- `/^{z:$/, /^-}\$$/` specifies the start and end of the range.

**To replace with null string**

You can use the substitute command as

```
$ sed '/^{z:/, /-}\$$/s/.*//' input







hello
world
```

Comment: @EtanReisner I too have no idea what null string is but assumed so. Will remove that part if its wrong

Comment: The OP said "null character" presumably meaning `\0`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly try the following perl solution

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

undef $/;     ## register separator is undefined
my $t=<>;     ## slurp all input to $t

$t =~ s/\{z:.*?\n-\}/\0/gs;   ## substitute patt by \0
print $t;
```

Usage: perl thisscript input

If you need a more complex transformation inside the pattern I would suggest:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

undef $/;     ## register separator is undefined
my $t=<>;     ## slurp all input to $t

$t =~ s/(\{z:.*?\n-\})/norm($1)/gse;   ## substitute patt by its norm
print $t;

sub norm{ my $s = shift;
    ## transform $s
    return $s
}
```